# After rotation border of image is getting fuzzy ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, cgcontext, cgaffinetransform

While developing a photography based app i need to rotate an image. But after rotating an image it's border gets fuzzy. i have attached screen shot of this..

[image]

As you can see first image looks good but other images which are rotated are not looking good.

here is my code.....

```
        [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [img setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [img.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]];
        [img.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
        [img setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation*3.14/180)];
```

I have used this solution...

```
CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians);
[sourceImage drawInRect:rect];
```

But how to work with this code when image has boarders.

Please give your valuable response .....

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate an image the border pixels are not antialiased: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4139695/1124373).

The solution, as odd as it sounds, is to give the image a 1px transparent border. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071996/1124373) gives the code to add the 1px transparent border to your image.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of aliasing effect. Search for "anti-aliasing".